# Beefy justification subscription is not working

Tags: rpc, finality, beefy, justification, subscription

I would like to subscribe to the beefy justification stream on Rococo. The rpc for getFinalizedHead works fine, but I also require the justifications themselves.

When I try to subscribe to the justifications using (in the polkadot-apps-ui/Developer/Javascript section):

```
const unsub = await api.rpc.beefy.subscribeJustifications((header) => {
     console.log(`The last block has a timestamp of ${header}`);
});
```

I get the following error (when a new header is finalized):

```
h@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.151b50df8afdab63.js:50:76373
createTypeUnsafe@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.151b50df8afdab63.js:50:163502
_formatOutput@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.151b50df8afdab63.js:50:5692
_formatResult@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.151b50df8afdab63.js:50:3182
d@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.151b50df8afdab63.js:50:4503
21899/y/this.__internal__onSocketMessageSubscribe@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.151b50df8afdab63.js:50:24109
21899/y/this.__internal__onSocketMessage@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.151b50df8afdab63.js:50:23088
```

How can I get this to work?

Any help is much appreciated
Please and thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting this !

Looks like the definition of `beefy::subscribeJustifications()` from `polkadot-js/api` is outdated. Published a PR that should fix it: https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/pull/5740 . The change will take effect after `polkadot-js/apps` is redeployed. Not sure exactly when this will happen, but will keep an eye on it.

Comment: Thank you addressing this issue!!

Comment: I tried the lastest polkadot beta release and the issue persists.
`"@polkadot/api": "^8.14.2-12"`
`DRR: createType(BeefySignedCommitment):: decodeU8a: failed at 0x01046d6880a430184b7172679dd2cb91… on commitment (index 0/2): {"payload":"BeefyPayload","blockNumber":"BlockNumber","validatorSetId":"ValidatorSetId"}:: decodeU8a: failed at 0x01046d6880a430184b7172679dd2cb91… on payload (index 0/3): Vec<(BeefyPayloadId,Bytes)>:: decodeU8a: failed at 0xbe1473009332000000000000387edaf5… ...`