# Rococo node crashing due to beefy gadget

Tags: rococo, finality, sync, beefy

I am attempting to run a Rococo node from scratch. The command I am using is `./target/release/polkadot --chain=rococo --base-path /hdd/work/fat-db/rococo-actual --enable-offchain-indexing true --sync fast-unsafe --blocks-pruning 300`.
The node syncs upto the lastest block just fine, but then it starts to log several messages such as  `Marking block 7480842 as BEEFY Mandatory.`. When it comes down to block `5920792` the node crashes with the following error

```
2023-10-15 13:59:14  Marking block 5920792 as BEEFY Mandatory.    
2023-10-15 13:59:14 Error: Backend("Could not find initial validator set"). Terminating.    
2023-10-15 13:59:14 Essential task `beefy-gadget` failed. Shutting down service.    
Error: 
   0: Other: Essential task failed.

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
```

I want to just run a Rococo node with beefy running so that I can log out the beefy justifications that are currently unavailable in the rpc  [Beefy justification subscription is not working](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10107/beefy-justification-subscription-is-not-working)

Any help is much appreciated.
Please and Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having comes from doing the initial sync using `fast-unsafe` combined with `--blocks-pruning 300`.
What happens is:

- you start with empty DB -> no BEEFY state/info whatsoever,
- fast syncing takes you straight to latest state (so no old state), AND `--blocks-pruning 300` means when reaching HEAD you only have last 300 headers,
- BEEFY cannot initialize because your node doesn't have any info on block `5920792` (which is BEEFY genesis on Rococo).

### Solution

1. Run your **initial sync** without `--blocks-pruning` (defaults to `archive-canonical`).
2. Once node is synced to HEAD of chain and BEEFY is initialized (you can see BEEFY finalized blocks happening in logs or RPC), BEEFY state will be saved to DB and can be reused for subsequent runs
3. At this point you can stop the node, and restart it with `--blocks-pruning 300` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you @adrian. I am trying this now...

Comment: Also, on a related note, I was wondering if there is any way to get my node to ask for and download a particular block from its peers. This would save me the 100gb of disk space :)

Comment: If that still doesn't work, do a `--sync full` at least until block 5920792 then it should be fine.

Comment: Issue is still present even without `--blocks-pruning` - only workaround right now is using `--sync full`.
Opened https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/1885 to track the fix for `--sync fast(-unsafe)`.

Comment: is there anyway I can get a Rococo snapshot? The full sync is really slow! It has been 6 hrs and only ~400k blocks synced...
Can you think of any other way to get beefy justifications?

Comment: You can build `polkadot` binary from latest master which contains fix (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1888) - then you can run `--sync fast-unsafe`

Comment: Thank you!! @adrian will `--blocks-pruning 100` work?

Comment: Run without `--blocks-pruning 100` initially, once it is synced and BEEFY initialized, you can restart node with `--blocks-pruning 100` (and continuing from where it left off).